# AngularJS dependency injection of value inside of module.config

Tags: angularjs

Trying to setup some helpers value to the module. Tried with service and value and it didn't help:

```
var finance = angular.module('finance', ['finance.services'])
    .value("helpers", {
        templatePath: function (name) {
            return '/areas/scripts/finance/templates/' + name + '/index.html';
        }
    })
    .config(['$routeProvider', 'helpers', function ($routeProvider, helpers) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: helpers.getTemplatePath('dashboard'),
            controller: DashboardController
        })            
        .when('/people', {
            templateUrl: '/areas/scripts/app/people/index.html',
            controller: PeopleController
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/dashboard'
        });
}]);
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: How do you solve it then?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to inject a value object `helpers` in the config block of a AngularJS module and this is not allowed. You can only inject constants and providers in the config block.

The AngularJS [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module) (section: "Module Loading & Dependencies") gives the insight into this:

> A module is a collection of configuration and run blocks which get
> applied to the application during the bootstrap process. In its
> simplest form the module consist of collection of two kinds of blocks:
>
> **Configuration blocks** - get executed during the provider registrations
> and configuration phase. Only providers and constants can be injected
> into configuration blocks. This is to prevent accidental instantiation
> of services before they have been fully configured.
>
> **Run blocks** - get
> executed after the injector is created and are used to kickstart the
> application. Only instances and constants can be injected into run
> blocks. This is to prevent further system configuration during
> application run time.

Comment: Actually I have already read it but also I was too dumb to recall it. Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

Instead of `.value` you can use `.constant`. Then you can use your service in `.config` part.

Comment: managed to get this to work in 1.0.6 by using .constant, as fedor.belov says

Answer (score 1):

Your helper method is called `templatePath` and you are calling it inside `.config` as `getTemplatePath`. Shouldn't it be:

```
when('/', {
            templateUrl: helpers.templatePath('dashboard'),
            controller: DashboardController
     })
```