# Angular.js: value() not injected in config()

Tags: angularjs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [AngularJS dependency injection of value inside of module.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903338/angularjs-dependency-injection-of-value-inside-of-module-config)

I am having trouble getting the value() injected into the app.config(). Here's the code (coffeescript)

```
window.app = angular.module("app", [])

app.value("template_path", "assets/angular/templates/users")

app.config(["$routeProvider","template_path" ($routeProvider, template_path) ->
  console.log template_path
```

it is throwing an "Unknown provider: template_path from app" error

Could it be that the config() method cannot be injected with value() set values?
I am using 1.0.2

Comment: This is essentially the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903338/angularjs-dependency-injection-of-value-inside-of-module-config/

Comment: I see, I need to work on my ST search-fu :) Could some moderator close this for duplication then?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you were suspecting correctly: values can't be injected into the config block. **The config block can only have constants and providers injected**.

Comment: This is correct... see [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.Module#constant)