# Best way to override module values/constants in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have written a module in angularJS that encapsulates all the backend communications. For greater flexibility I have the api prefix as a constant value on the module (could be value since I am not using it in the config phase).
so something like

```
angular.module('myapp.data').constant('apiPrefix', '/api/data');
```

Now I want to use this module from two different applications. One uses /api1/data and the other one /api2/data and I would like to change this during the config phase of the application.
I know how to do that with a provider, but having a provider to hold a value seems like an overkill to me. Can I modify used modules constants or values from the application config phase?

something like:

```
angular.module("data", [])
.value('apiPrefix', '/api/data')
.factory('display', function(apiPrefix){
  return {
    pref: function(){
      console.log(apiPrefix);
      return apiPrefix;
    }
  }
});


angular.module("myApp",['data'])
.config(['apiPrefix', function(prefix){
  prefix = 'https:/api/data'; 
}])
.controller("Example", function($scope, display) {
   $scope.prefix = display.pref;
});
```

Comment: Not sure but you can try to do it at `run` stage.

Comment: Yeah you can update a value at the run stage, and you can inject a constant in config but since it's a constant it can't be changed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035568/angular-js-value-not-injected-in-config

Comment: So what you are saying is that it should be a value instead of a constant in the module and modify it on run stage of the application instead of the config?

Comment: Why don't you give it a try :)

Comment: Indeed that is what we're saying.  Config needs to be run on everything that could have config before it is injected into anything hence the problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

to override the module values, you can redefine the angular value in later modules. I believe it should not be done module config time.

```
angular.module("data", [])
.value('apiPrefix', '/api/data')
.factory('Display', function(apiPrefix){
  return {
    pref: function(){
      return apiPrefix;
    }
  }
});




angular.module('myapp', ['data'])
  .value('apiPrefix', '/api2/data')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, Display)    {
      $scope.name = Display.pref();
  });
```

see the plunker here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/k806WE

same thing is applicable for angular constants too.

Comment: Great solution. I kind of fill bad that I didn't know that since I could have accidentally override a module constant or value, since I am using them a lot. Good thing I am always trying to create unique descriptive names.

Comment: Thanks @mxa055. Actually, I prefer to keep constants and values like configuration or backend api endpoints in a seperate config module.

Answer (score 11):

Our module

```
angular.module("data", [])
  .constant('apiPrefix', '/api/data');
```

We can override `constant` fully, like `value`.

```
angular.module('myapp', ['data'])
  .constant('apiPrefix', '/api2/data');
```

also we can override fully in `config`

```
angular.module('myapp', ['data'])
    .config(function ($provide) {
        $provide.constant('apiPrefix', '/api2/data');
    });
```

also we can override fully or partially (if object) in `run`

```
angular.module('myapp', ['data'])
    .run(function (apiPrefix) {
        apiPrefix = '/api2/data';
    });
```

But if we want to override `constant` with object partially in config (not in run), we can do something like this

```
angular.module("module1", [])
    .constant('myConfig', {
        param1: 'value1' ,
        param2: 'value2'
    });

angular.module('myapp', ['data'])
    .config(function ($provide, myConfig) {
        $provide.constant(
            'myConfig', 
            angular.extend(myConfig, {param2: 'value2_1'});
        );
    });
```

Comment: Reference myConfig with string to override extend values on module myapp.
angular.module('myapp', ['data'])
    .config(function ($provide, myConfig) {
        $provide.constant(
            myConfig, 
            angular.extend('myConfig', {param2: 'value2_1'});
        );
    });

Comment: Thanks. Yes, `$provide.constant('myConfig', ...` - 'myConfig' must be a string!

Answer (score 1):

Angular modules, controllers, etc. can be contained within functions, if-statements, etc. They do not have to be at the top level. So, you could include this in your code:

```
if (environmentOne()) {
  module.value('apiPrefix','api1/data');
} else {
  module.value('apiPrefix','api2/data');
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This sounds interesting, but I would hate to have to do something like that in my module for every different application that might use me. It short of creates a "dependency" between the module and its users.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I misread your question, and thought it was a matter of development/staging/production environments. Khanmizan's answer is better.