# AngularJS - How to deflate and encode/decode to base64 all jsons request?

Tags: json, http, base64, angularjs, deflate

Lets say i have several $resources and some $http around my angular application:

```
myApp.factory('Note', function($resource) {

  return $resource('http://', {id: '@id'}, 
    { 'index': { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
      'update': { method: 'PUT'},
    });
  });
```

with controller

```
myApp.controller('NotesController',function NotesController($scope, Note, AuthenticationService) {

$scope.notes = Note.index({}, function(data){
    console.log('success, got data: ', data);
    $scope.response = "yoy!"
  }, function(err){
    console.log('error, got data: ', err);
    $scope.response = "yay!"
  }); 
});
```

and some request are made by $http directly like authentication

```
var request = $http.post('http://', {email: email, password: password});
```

Where and How i can tell angular to deflate and encode/decode JSONs to base64 before the actual request is made / response is receive?

I quess i will wrap external libraries for deflate and encode/decode into factory. And then this factory will be injected somehere? 
Like $httpBackend ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should have a look at the **request / response transformers** for the `$http` service: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http

Request / response transformers are simply functions that can be invoked before content is sent / handed back to the caller. You can specify transforming functions globally (for all requests / responses) as well as per-request basis:

> To override these transformation locally, specify transform functions
>   as transformRequest and/or transformResponse properties of the config
>   object. To globally override the default transforms, override the
>   $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest and
>   $httpProvider.defaults.transformResponse properties of the
>   $httpProvider.

To define global request / response transformers one would write the code along those lines (it is more like pseudo-code, won't work in all browsers, see notes about Base64 below):

```
angular.module('sample', [], function($httpProvider) {

    $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = function(data, headersGetter) {
        return btoa(JSON.stringify(data));
    };

    $httpProvider.defaults.transformResponse = function(data, headersGetter) {
        return JSON.parse(atob(data));
    };

})
```

Of course your transforming code could be more sophisticated and depend on request / response headers but the general idea is here. The jsFiddle with the code (check the console to see that a request gets transformed, you need to use Mozilla or a WebKit browser): http://jsfiddle.net/Ydt5j/

For the actual conversion from / to Base64 check this question: [How can you encode a string to Base64 in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/246801/1418796)

Comment: thank you, for your reply. I would love to do something like `$httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = function(request){return Base64Factory.encode(request)};` in my myApp.config(function(){}) ,but as far as i know i cannot inject factory in config function. Would you please be more verbose and help me with this? Thank you

Comment: I have also tried to accomplish in myApp.run(function(){}) ,but still have no success?

Comment: @Mark you can't inject providers into run block so trying to inject `$httpProvider` will result in an error. Similarly, one can't inject services into configuration blocks. Updated the answer with more info, but you can check this question as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12903544/1418796

Comment: @all no doubt, that pkozlowski.opensource answer is correct. I don't know why i urged on my pseudo-requirement that i have to wrap base64 functionality into factory/service. But at the finish i end up with .provide() which can be injected into config function. It works, but somehow i feel that it is not ideal solution? Please leave your comments..

Comment: Using a provider (.provide()) is not ideal here since providers should create new services and here you are just using it as a means of injecting something to a config block. If you really need to have it injectable maybe a constant is a way to go? But if you don't need a general purpose Base64 service (for me it sounds more like a utility function) I wouldn't bother. If the above works for you, please accept / up-vote the anwser :-)

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource as you can feel, i am using [angular-app](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app) as my starting block. Do you mind that i will raise up one more question regarding to the AuthenticationService and poke you to there?

Comment: @Jakub we can discuss https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app related stuff on the AngularJS mailing list.

Answer (score 2):

```
angular.module('services.base64',[]);
angular.module('services.base64').provider('base64', function () {

  this.encode = function(str) {
    return base64_encode(str);
  }

  this.decode = function(str) {
    return base64_decode(str);
  }

  this.$get = function() {
    return {};
  }

});

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['services.base64'])

myApp.config(['base64Provider', function (base64Provider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = function(request){return base64Provider.encode(request)};

    $httpProvider.defaults.transformResponse = function(response){return base64Provider.decode(response)};
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

this is how i do in filter.
item.htmlBody contains base64 encoded text with html tag

```
// in template
<div ng-bind-html="item.htmlBody | decodeBase64">{{item.htmlBody}}</div>

//inside controller.js

.filter('decodeBase64', function(){
   return function(text){
   return atob(text);
   }
})
```

well, i know this doesnt exactly answer the question, but with some minor tweak, you can get what you want (targetting future person with the same problem)