# Javascript ATOB and BTOA doesn't work

Tags: javascript, java, spring, angular

I'm sending an object from the backend. The problem is that payload is a byte[] and it seems like spring converts it to String64.

I'm getting a strange output in the frontend so I tried to convert it to normal string and I get

```
 _co.atob is not a function
```

How do I convert this??

Backend

```
    @GetMapping("docker/container/{containerName}/logs")
public List<Frame> getContainerLogs(@PathVariable String containerName) {
    Container container = dockerService.getContainer(containerName);
    return dockerService.getDockerLogs(container);
}
```

frontend

ts:

```
getLogs() {
this.dockerService.getLogs(this.name).subscribe(logs => {
  this.logs = logs;
  console.log(logs);
});
```

html:

```
   <p *ngFor="let log of logs; let idx = index;"><span class="logsLine">{{idx}}: </span>

        <span>{{atob(log.payload)}}</span>
      </p>
```

example

```
{"streamType":"STDERR","payload":"JUdUTS1JLU1VRklMUk5EV05TVUMsIEZpbGUgL3Y3NTRxYWJhc2VfZ3RtbHgvZ2Jscy9tdW1wcy50YmxzIHN1Y2Nlc3NmdWxseSBydW5kb3duCg=="}
```

Comment: `window.atob` also doesn't work https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_atob.asp

Comment: Have you taken a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14090619/angularjs-how-to-deflate-and-encode-decode-to-base64-all-jsons-request

Comment: i'm using angular 6

Comment: What browser are you using? Because [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=atob) says even IE11 should be fine.