# Injecting Dependencies in config() modules - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Currently in app.js i have the following routes:

```
var gm = angular.module('gm', ['gm.services','gm.directives','gm.filters','gm.controllers','ngSanitize']);

gm.config(['$routeProvider', 'Path', function($routeProvider, Path) {

    $routeProvider.when('/login', { 
        templateUrl: Path.view('application/authentication/login.html'), 
        controller: 'authController' 
    });

    $routeProvider.when('/dashboard', { 
        templateUrl: Path.view('application/dashboard/index.html'), 
        controller: 'dashboardController' 
    }); 

    $routeProvider.otherwise({ 
        redirectTo: '/login'
    });

}]);
```

I'm trying to inject the Path dependency as you can see. Although i get an error saying it can't find this provider. I think this is because config module providers are executed first before anything else. below is my Path provider definition in "services.js"

```
gm.factory("Path", function() {
  return {
    view: function(path) {
      return 'app/views/' + path; 
    },
    css: function(path) {
      return 'app/views/' + path; 
    },
    font: function(path) {
      return 'app/views/' + path; 
    },
    img: function(path) {
      return 'app/views/' + path; 
    },
    js: function(path) {
      return 'app/views/' + path; 
    },
    vendor: function(path) {
      return 'app/views/' + path; 
    },
    base: function(path) {
      return '/' + path; 
    }
  }
});
```

how can i inject this provider into a config module?

Comment: So many code duplication... It would be better to create a function that will return generated path and use it

Comment: How do you mean? Example?

Comment: Like this - http://jsfiddle.net/TBn7u/

Comment: A related  question, I figured it'd be worth it to link to: [Can $q and $http be injected in the .config section](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20626514/320399)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937267/inject-service-in-app-config

Answer (score 58, accepted):

In `.config` you can only use providers (e.g. `$routeProvider`). in `.run` you can only use instances of services (e.g. `$route`). You have a factory, not a provider. [See this snippet with the three ways of creating this:  Service, Factory and Provider](https://gist.github.com/Mithrandir0x/3639232)
They also mention this in the angular docs https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Comment: This answer gives explanation, Tongamite's gives a solution.

Comment: Isn't this answer 'now' wrong since it is possible to inject the factory in config by appending 'Provider' (as per the other answer )

Comment: Hi @sumeet can you elaborate more? angular appends Provider to your service name if you define one. this has happened since the jurassic. The other answer is basically using a Provider of a service in the config part.

Comment: what @sumeet says is you can inject factory in config BUT use it with `yourFactoryProvider.$get().yourFunction()`.

Answer (score 84):

1. `angular.config` only accepts Providers
2. every service, factory etc are instances of Provider

So to inject a service in config you just need to call the Provider of the service by adding 'Provider' to it's name.

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .service('FooService', function(){
    //...etc
  })
  .config(function(FooServiceProvider){
    //...etc
  });
```

According to the angularjs Provider [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers)

> ... if you define a Factory recipe, an empty Provider type with the `$get` method set to your factory function is automatically created under the hood.

So if you have a factory (or service) such as:

```
.factory('myConfig', function(){
  return {
    hello: function(msg){
      console.log('hello ' + msg)
    }
  }
})
```

You first need to invoke your factory using the `$get` method before accessing the returned object:

```
.config(function(myConfigProvider){
   myConfigProvider
     .$get()
     .hello('world');
});
```

Comment: I have a factory that I've done this with, but none of the methods are available.  Any ideas?

Comment: i updated the answer to give an example how to access your factory methods. I hope it helps.

Comment: Your answer is wrong, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24714452/1154692 "You can only inject Providers (not instances) into config blocks
"

Comment: @SmartyTwiti Yes exactly, can inject the Provider of your service/factory into the config block. Here is a working jsfiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/vefatkwL/

Comment: I might be wrong, but I guess it's wrong to call `.$get()` manually, as service stops being a singleton.

Comment: What if my service returns data that  i want to use inside my component (angular 1.5.8) ? when I try `ctrl.xxx = provider.$get().funcName()`  i'm getting an error that **ctrl is undefined**

Comment: @gilad, in view of the syntax, i suspect your trying to access your service in a controller, in which case you can call your service directly without using 'provider'. Regarding your error, if you define your object first, you will then be able to assign a property to it (ie. `var ctrl = {}`). If you've just got started with angular, i suggest you read about [controllerAs](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1#controlleras-view-syntax) best practices

Comment: This, BY FAR, is the cleanest and simplest solution!  Thanks! +1

Answer (score 14):

You should use constant for that, because it's the only thing you can inject in the config phase other than providers.

```
angular.module("yourModule").constant("paths", {
  base: function(){ ... }
});
```

Comment: ah perfect! so its possible for a constant to have functions? i thought they could only return strings..?

Comment: Yes it does thank you! although i have created a provider as Eduard has given really good resources to finally begin getting my head around the AngularJS architecture.

Comment: Useful link: http://twofuckingdevelopers.com/2014/06/angularjs-best-practices-001-constants/

Answer (score 2):

This [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/DZS_YoeCcds) helped me when I was trying to figure out the same thing, basically

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {
                templateUrl:'views/main.html',
                controller:'MainController',
                resolve: {
                    recentPosts: ['$q', 'backendService', function($q, backendService){
                        var deferred = $q.defer();
                        backendService.getRecentPosts().then(
                            function(data) {
                                var result = data.result;
                                deferred.resolve(result);
                            },
                            function(error) {
                                deferred.reject(error);
                            }
                        );
                        return deferred.promise;
                    }]
                }
            })
```