# Can $q and $http be injected in the .config section

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to inject $q in the config section of my module? Below is my sample config section.

```
.config(['$q', function ($q) {
    var func = function (inp) {
        var def = $q.defer();

        if (inp == 1)
            def.resolve("Success");
        else
            def.reject("Failure");

        return def.promise;
    };

    alert(func(1));
}]);
```

The first error i am getting is 
*Uncaught Error: Unknown provider: $q from ReportModule*
If i change

```
.config(['$q', function ($q) {}])
```

to

```
.config(['$qProvider', function ($q) {}])
```

then i get a error saying *Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'defer' from ReportModule*

Seems like i cant inject $q in config section. Is that the case or am i doing something wrong? I have a usecase where i need to use $q and $http in the config section of my module for initialization. Is there some technique for doing this?

Comment: `run` method on module runs just after config stage, maybe you can use that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Correct--you can't inject $http or $q from a config function. They are not available yet (they're also being configured!).

Comment: See my answer below for a way to inject `$http` and `$q`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`angular.injector`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.injector)to load `$http` and `$q`, and probably other services in your config block:

```
angular.module('myApp').config(function () {
    var injector = angular.injector(['ng']),
        http = injector.get('$http'),
        q = injector.get('$q');
});
```

Comment: The problem with this is you're injecting possibly unconfigured services. There's a good reason why `$http` and `$q` aren't available in the config phase--configuration is not guaranteed to be deterministic. This may or may not work all the time in every circumstance.

Comment: That's true, it should be used with caution and isn't a best practice. But it is possible.

Comment: -1 since `angular.injector(['ng'])` creates a new injector, which means that you will get new instances of everything you get using that injector. See [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AlexanderS/Lexb8da8/). This is hard to understand and may cause very unexpected results. '$q' and '$http' shouldn't be used in config-phase directly. There are other possibilities.

Comment: @AlexS could you post alternatives to inject http and q? thx!!

Comment: @Miquel Depends on your environment and needs. In our environment we use manual bootstraping of angular and use normal javascript to make http-calls. The callbacks of the http-calls start the manual bootstraping...

Comment: @AlexS thx, so you mean that you use plain ajax calls and also you have your own promise class to use in config phase?

Comment: @Miquel Yes we use one plain ajax call in the head-sction to get relevant data for initialization. This data is stored in a global variable. In config phase we just access this variable. No need for our own promis api. Not very elegant. We plan to include the initialization data in our html page as it is served by the same servlet...

Answer (score 4):

It is possible for me (when routing configure):

```
resolve: {
   simpleStringParam: ["$q", "$timeout", function($q, $timeout){
      var deferred = $q.defer();
          $timeout(function(){
              deferred.resolve("Allo!");
          },8000);
      return deferred.promise;
   }]
}
```

Comment: khoailang, it is just example :) $timeout is a way to emulate async operation. Instead of it you can use $http, any async service or smth you want