# AngularJS: How to use $q in your config phase for a unit test?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, promise

I have an angular service responsible for loading a *config.json* file. I would like to call it in my *run phase* so I set that json in my *$rootContext* and hence, it is available in the future for everyone.

Basically, this is what I've got:

```
angular.module('app.core', []).run(function(CoreRun) {
    CoreRun.run();
});
```

Where my CoreRun service is:

```
 angular.module('app.core').factory('CoreRun', CoreRun);

 CoreRun.$inject = ['$rootScope', 'config'];

 function CoreRun($rootScope, config) {
   function run() {
     config.load().then(function(response) {
       $rootScope.config = response.data;
     });
   }    
   return {
     run: run
   };
}
```

This works fine and the problem comes up when I try to *test* it. I want to spy on my config service so it returns a fake promise. However, I cannot make it since during the config phase for my test, services are not available and I cannot inject $q.

As far as I can see the only chance I have to mock my config service is there, in the config phase, since it is called by run block.

The only way I have found so far is generating the promise using jQuery which I really don't like.

```
beforeEach(module('app.core'));

var configSample;

beforeEach(module(function ($provide) {
   config = jasmine.createSpyObj('config', [ 'load' ]);
   config.load.and.callFake(function() {
     configSample = { baseUrl: 'someurl' };        
     return jQuery.Deferred().resolve({data: configSample}).promise();
   });
   provide.value('config', config);
}));

it('Should load configuration using the correspond service', function() {
  // assert
  expect(config.load).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect($rootScope.config).toBe(configSample);
});
```

Is there a way to make a more correct workaround?

**EDIT:** Probably worth remarking that this is an issue just when unit testing my run block.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can $q and $http be injected in the .config section](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20626514/can-q-and-http-be-injected-in-the-config-section)

Comment: Seems similar but completely different. The one you refer is about injecting $q in the config phase of a real module. This is about injecting $q in a run block during the config phase of a unit test, so you can mock it for being able to test your run block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that it is not possible to inject `$q` the right way, because function in your `run()` block fires immediately. `run()` block is considered a config phase in Angular, so `inject()` in tests only runs after config blocks, therefore even if you `inject()` `$q` in test, it will be `undefined`, because `run()` executes first.

After some time I was able to get `$q` in the `module(function ($provide) {})` block with one very dirty workaround. The idea is to create an extra angular module and include it in test before your application module. This extra module should also have a `run()` block, which is gonna publish `$q` to a global namespace. Injector will first call extra module's `run()` and then app module's `run()`.

```
angular.module('global $q', []).run(function ($q) {
    window.$q = $q;
});

describe('test', function () {

    beforeEach(function () {

        module('global $q');

        module('app.core');

        module(function ($provide) {
            console.log(window.$q); // exists
        });

        inject();

    });
});
```

This extra module can be included as a separate file for the test suite before spec files. If you put the module in the same file where the tests are, then you don't event need to use a global `window` variable, but just a variable within a file.

[Here is a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4vbmPA0xiVBBu9MLpsaq?p=preview) (see a "script.js" file)

**First solution (does not solve the issue):**

You actually can use `$q` in this case, but you have to inject it to a test file. Here, you won't really inject it to a unit under test, but directly to a test file to be able to use it inside the test. So it does not actually depend on the type of a unit under test:

```
// variable that holds injected $q service
var $q;

beforeEach(module(function ($provide) {
    config = jasmine.createSpyObj('config', [ 'load' ]);

    config.load.and.callFake(function() {
        var configSample = { baseUrl: 'someurl' };

        // create new deferred obj
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        // resolve promise
        deferred.resolve({ data: configSample });

        // return promise
        return deferred.promise;
   });

   provide.value('config', config);
}));

// inject $q service and save it to global (for spec) variable
// to be able to access it from mocks
beforeEach(inject(function (_$q_) {
    $q = _$q_;
}));
```

Resources:

- Read more about `inject()` - [angular.mock.inject](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.16/docs/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.inject)
- [$q](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.16/docs/api/ng/service/$q)

And one more note: *config* phase and *run* phase are two different things. *Config* block allows to use providers only, but in the *run* block you can inject pretty much everything (except providers). More info here - [Module Loading & Dependencies](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.16/docs/guide/module#module-loading-dependencies)

Comment: Yes, of course. I know the differences among them. I just wanted to mention that I would ideally need to inject $q in the config phase inside my test because it runs before my run block.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would try it as soon as I can. However, I want to remember to have already tested it and it didn't work because the second _beforeach_ is executed once my run block has already been executed and therefore, at that moment $q was undefined.

Comment: Indeed, it does not work. It might be because I need `$q` to have been injected when my run block is executed (trigger by `beforeEach(module('app.core'));`) and at that moment, `beforeEach(inject(function (_$q_)` did not happen yet.

Comment: @jbernal, yes, you are right and I was wrong, `$q` is `undefined`. `inject()` runs after `Core.run()` gets executed, and it seems that there is no way to use `$q` in `provide()` in this case. But I was able to workaround it in a veeery tricky way, I've updated the post.

Comment: Happy to see you found a solution! As you said it is not the best one but it works and it is for a test so you are not dirtying your source code. 

Using jQuery as I did is still valid if you already have it in your project as well. Everyone can choose whichever he likes more :)

Thanks for your help!