# AngularJs can't inject $provide and $injector services in module.run

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to define services dynamically in angularjs, as the docs says, [`$provide`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide) and [`$injector`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector) are services, thus they should be injectable in `module.run`..
I need to make the dynamic services available from app bootstrap, that's why i'm trying to define them in `module.run`

```
angular.module('remote.interface',[])
.run(['$provide', '$injector', function(provide, injector){
  // provide dynamically
}]);
```

but this ends up in an Error : `[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $provideProvider <- $provide`, and same eror for `$injector` if i try to remove $provide injection.
Where's the bug?

[EDIT]

after some research i tried something like this:

```
var module = angular.module('remote.interface',[])
.run([function(){
  var provide = module.provider(),
    injector = angular.injector();
    provide.value('my.val',{i:'am a value'});
    injector.get('my.val'); // this throws [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: my.valProvider <- my.val
}]);
```

even if i remove the `injector.get` call, if i try to inject `my.val`, for example, in another-module's controller, angular throws the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation for module and have a read at the comments in the example setup, particularly these comments.

**config**

> You can only inject Providers (not instances) into config blocks

**run**

> You can only inject instances (not Providers) into run blocks

[Here is an example setup on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZrejS/) injecting $provide and $injector correctly.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

```
angular.module('myModule', []).
  config(function(injectables) { // provider-injector
    // This is an example of config block.
    // You can have as many of these as you want.
    // You can only inject Providers (not instances)
    // into config blocks.
  }).
  run(function(injectables) { // instance-injector
    // This is an example of a run block.
    // You can have as many of these as you want.
    // You can only inject instances (not Providers)
    // into run blocks
  });
```