# Angular Inject $http into config or provider into run

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing, angular-route-segment

I am using angular-route-segment in my angular app and an trying to configure the segments from a json feed.

I have having problems with this, because I can't figure out how to inject `$http` into the `app.config` function. This fails with `Unknown provider: $http`

```
myApp.config(["$http", "$routeSegmentProvider", function ($http, $routeSegmentProvider) {
   /* setup navigation here calling $routeSegmentProvider.when a number of times */
}
```

So instead of injecting $http into `config`, I also tried injecting `$routeSegmentProvider` into `myApp.run`

```
myApp.run(["$http", "$routeSegment", function($http, $routeSegment) {
    /* can use $http here to get data, but $routeSegment is not the same here */
    /* $routeSegment does not have the when setup method */
}]);
```

I also tried

```
myApp.run(["$http", "$routeSegmentProvider", function($http, $routeSegmentProvider)
```

but I get `Unknown provider: $routeSegmentProviderProvider <- $routeSegmentProvider`

Comment: You can find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937267/inject-service-in-app-config

Comment: @DavidBohunek I think I came across that example before, but I wasn't able to get it to work for some reason. I decided to go with cliff.meyers answer for now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Providers can only be injected in the "config" phase and not the "run" phase. Conversely, a service such as $http will not have been initialized yet in the "config" phase and will only be available in the "run" phase.

A little trick to work around this is to define a variable in the parent function scope so that both the "config" and "run" blocks can have access to it:

```
var routeSegmentProvider = null;

myApp.config(["$routeSegmentProvider", function ($routeSegmentProvider) {
    routeSegmentProvider = $routeSegmentProvider;
}]);

myApp.run(["$http", function($http) {
  // access $http and routeSegmentProvider here
}]);
```

I'm not sure if you will encounter problems trying to call $routeSegmentProvider.setup() within the run phase as I haven't tried.  In the past I was able to use the same technique to register http response interceptors that depend on some custom services with the $httpProvider.

Comment: It works, though this might not be the *best* solution... I decided to go with this for now. Thanks!

Comment: Seems like a hack to use global variables.. Most of you will let this slip because it's front-end JS.

Comment: This code was originally wrapped in an IIFE but I had omitted it for brevity. Nothing about it requires use of global scope, it's just accessed via closure.