# Issue getting $rootScope injected into config of Angular?

Tags: angularjs

I am doing:

```
myApp.config([
  '$httpProvider', '$rootScope', function($httpProvider, $rootScope) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q) {
      return {
        responseError: function(rejection) {
          var defer;
          defer = $q.defer();
          if (rejection.status === 401) {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('api-error', rejection);
          }
          defer.reject(rejection);
          return defer.promise;
        },
        response: function(response) {
          var defer;
          defer = $q.defer();
          console.log(response);
          if (response.status === 401) {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('api-error', response);
            defer.reject(response);
          } else {
            defer.resolve(response);
          }
          return defer.promise;
        }
      };
    });
  }
]);
```

But I get an error that it cannot find `$rootScope`. I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25644039/angular-inject-http-into-config-or-provider-into-run) and it says to do some weird global variable stuff, which seems like a bad idea.
So how can I redirect to another route upon a 401 status?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot get to $rootScope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486769/cannot-get-to-rootscope)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Inject `$rootScope` in the interceptor, not in the configuration function:

```
myApp.config([
  '$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, $rootScope) {
     ...
```

Comment: Do I need to use the `array` if I will minify my code later?

Comment: and what about accessing `$state` as well?

Comment: Yes, you have to. But I much prefer using ngAnnotate and let it do that work for me at build time.

Comment: Regarding $state, well it's another service that can be injected in your interceptor as well.

Comment: I get `Circular dependency found: $state <- $http <- $templateFactory <- $view <- $state` when trying to include `$state`

Comment: Ah, I see. Then you'll have to use the `$injector` service and borrow the `$state` service  (using `$injector.get('$state')`) from it instead of injecting `$state`.