# Making a GET request in AngularJS's config

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[Similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25644039/angular-inject-http-into-config-or-provider-into-run) but doesn't appear to work in this case. I'm using [Angular-UI's Google Maps API](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api/GoogleMapApi), which requires configuration like so:

```
.config(function(uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider) {
    uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure({
        //    key: 'your api key',
        v: '3.20', //defaults to latest 3.X anyhow
        libraries: 'weather,geometry,visualization'
    });
})
```

I don't want to have my API key directly in here, I'd like to load it in from my server using a route via a GET request (`'/api/googleAPI'`). However, when I try:

```
 .config(function($http, uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider) {
```

I get:

```
 Failed to instantiate module myApp due to: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $http
```

Are there any workarounds for this or should I just brazenly chuck my API key in here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### based on @ryeballar's suggestion

After reading the link that @ryeballer provided in the comments for my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34661845/1121919), there is a much simpler workaround that doesn't require you to mess with the pre-bootstrapping processing or `XMLHttpRequests` or anything suggested in the **atypical** solution above.

```
.config(function(uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider) {

    var $injector = angular.injector(['ng'])
    var $http = $injector.get('$http')

    $http.get(<url to your key>)
    .then(function(rsp){
        var data = rsp;
        uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure({
            key: data.key,
            v: '3.20', //defaults to latest 3.X anyhow
            libraries: 'weather,geometry,visualization'
        })
     })
})
```

*I'd argue that this should probably be the selected answer given it's simplicity and that it operates within the typical angular post-bootstrapping lifecycle*

Comment: This is nice, but unlike the other solution it runs asynchronously. That's either a feature or a problem, depending on what the developer needs this initialization for.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any workarounds for this or should I just brazenly chuck my API key in here?

**No** don't put your API key in there, there are workarounds.

---

There are 2 basic phases for angular when it's loading/injecting/setting up dependencies.  There is the **config** phase and then there is the **post-config** phase.  (These aren't official names of phases, it's just how I describe them).

#### config phase

In the **config** phase, the only things that are available for injection are *-Providers* type constructs.  This means that anything you typically inject inside a service or a controller **aren't** available for injection in your configuration function.

#### post-config phase

Once you're application has been bootstrapped, configured, etc., then you can inject your typical injectable dependencies (e.g. $http, $q, $templateCache, etc.)

## typical solution

So in order to solve your issue, what I suggest is if you can't leverage something like `module.run( function($http){ $http.get(<url to your config>) })`
then you need to maybe forgo using `$http` and use a standard `XMLHttpRequest` for this bit of logic.

## atypical solution

In the app I am working on, we have a similar need to load up some non-angular config data via a .txt file.  Here's what I've done:

First postpone the automatic angular bootstrapping process (meaning I've left out the typical `ng-app` in my main index file).  Then load the .txt file via:

```
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open( 'GET', './version.txt' );
client.onload = function()
{
    kickoffAngular(client.responseText)
}
client.send();
```

Assuming your text is something simple like a key/value pair, each pair on a newline, you can parse the `responseText` like so:

```
kickoffAngular = function(text){
   var kvPairs = text.split('\n')
   kvPairs.forEach(function(kv){
       var pair = kv.split('=')
       var key = pair[0]
       var val = pair[1]
       ... do something with them
   })
}
```

Then bootstrap Angular via:

```
angular.bootstrap( document, <app name> )
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks for the detail. Do you have any suggested resources for doing the XMLHttpRequest? SO is a bit of a quagmire here and everything I've seen seems super convoluted for something so simple...

Comment: `client.responseText` will be the contents of your XMLHttpRequest response.  You can access that in the `onLoad` function to get what you need.  I will update the answer to reflect that.

Comment: You can probably stay way from using `XMLHttpRequest` by using the `angular.injector()` method. See this **[article](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/10/22/asynchronously-bootstrapping-angularjs-applications-with-server-side-data)**.

Comment: @ryeballar I actually like your link's solution for the pre-bootstrapping process, it would be nice to be able to leverage angular's $http & $q services prior to bootstrapping the app.  Thanks.