# AngularFire 0.9 resolve with UI router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire, angular-ui-router

I've followed a tutorial [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html#section-routes) but somehow getting this mistake

```
   Unknown provider: currentAuthProvider <- currentAuth
```

i added currentAuth to all my controllers, what might be wrong?

```
 Firebase 2.0.4 
 AngularFire 0.9.0
```

Here's the routes file:

```
      .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

     $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

     $stateProvider

         .state('home', {
         url: '/',
         templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
         controller: "homeCtrl",
         resolve: {
             "currentAuth": ["userFactory", function(userFactory) {
                 return userFactory.$waitForAuth();
             }]
         }
     })
```

i have only two modules:

```
      var warp = angular.module('warp', [
     'firebase',
     'ui.router'
 ])
```

and this is one of controllers:

```
     angular.module('warp')
    .controller("signupCtrl", ["$rootScope", '$scope', 'userFactory', '$window', '$firebase', '$location', 'USERS', 'currentAuth',
        function($rootScope, $scope, userFactory, $window, $firebase, $location, USERS, currentAuth) {
```

Comment: What is the order of your `script` includes? `angular.min.js` has to come first, then `firebase.js`, then `angularfire.min.js`, then `app.js`

Comment: Checked one more time — everything is like correct in the order of scripts.

Comment: Post the contents of your `var app = angular.module( ... )` declaration (the `...` part is important).

Comment: Why `userFactory` instead of `Auth` like the tutorial says?

Comment: i had this factory before i decided to implement the route security.

Comment: There's not enough code here to repro the problem or understand it. See [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It is not even working for me, whatever I do

Answer (score 3):

Check your HTML partial view and remove the **ng-controller** declaration.

NgRoute instantiates the controller for you and binds it to the DOM defined in your view, so there is no need to specify the controller with **ng-controller** in the view's partial HTML.

This works:

```
<!-- in it's own HTML file, say  views/signupCtrl.html -->
<div>  <!-- Look, no need for ng-controller="signupCtrl"... -->
  ...signup Form etc...
</div>
```

What happens if you **do** leave a ng-controller definition in there (which I suspect is what you did) is that angular will try to instantiates the controller twice:

- Once when it encounters it when loading the DOM, at which point **currentAuth** won't be defined, so you would get an **unknow provider** error if it's listed as a dependency in your controller.
- Once upon **resolve** completing.

Comment: Helped me too, thanks! Didn't know that and this is a serious thing.

Answer (score -1):

You need to inject 'currentAuth' object only to the Controller where you handle sign-in.
Worked for me when i deleted it from all other Controllers.

Comment: There is no reason a service couldn't be injected into multiple controllers. If that's not working, then it's likely a bug in the service code.