# AngularJs on-click not firing in base template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am using AngularJs and Firebase, try to get the Angularfire User Authentication working. But had some problem.

So I had an on-click event inside nav that will popup the user auth windows.

index.html

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
   <li><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
   <li ng-hide="authData"><a href="" ng-click="auth.$authWithOAuthPopup('google')">Login</a></li>
   <li ng-show="authData"><a href="" ng-click="auth.$unauth()">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

app.js

```
app.factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth", function($firebaseAuth){
  return $firebaseAuth(ref);
}]);

app.controller("HomeCtrl", ["$scope", "Auth", "currentAuth", function($scope, Auth, currentAuth) {
  $scope.auth = Auth;
  $scope.auth.$onAuth(function(authData) {
    $scope.authData = authData;
  });
}]);

$stateProvider.state("home", {
  controller: "HomeCtrl",
  url: "/",
  templateUrl: "partials/home.html",
  resolve: {
     "currentAuth": ["Auth", function(Auth) {
        return Auth.$waitForAuth();
    }]
  }
})
```

When I click on the `Login` in the nav nothing happens, but if I had the code as  partials file and load into the `ui-view`, then it works.

How can I fix it, so that on every page's nav will work the same. I had a temporary solution, which is to load everything in the body as a partials. But that means I have to repeat my nav code on every single partials, and I don't want to do that.

Yes... I tried `ng-controller="HomeCtrl"` on the nav, there's no need to do that. (See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27975745/3927928)

EDIT: Sample code on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wD3sVuYA4FF7a6CJoWFG?p=preview)

Comment: $waitForAuth() only waits for the auth state to resolve. It does not wait until the auth state resolves to a valid login (it could be null). If you want to use this with routing you should redirect to a "please authenticate" screen when $waitForAuth() resolves to null and then redirect back to home after.

Comment: @Kato I'm new to angular, how can I do that?

Comment: Check out [the guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/), which has a section on routing, and [angularFire-seed](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire-seed), which implements these strategies. Give those docs a serious read-through, and you'd do well to do the same with the Angular tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I created a directive for navbar and load it on the base template, works now

Answer (score 0):

if the navbar is outside the ui-view, then it is not under the influence of the controller which ui-router binds to that ui-view.   You should have a separate controller, i.e. `navbarController`, which can be bound statically to the navbar element with `ng-controller`, separate from the ui-view.  Within that controller, you can add all of the shared code which will be visible on all pages.  Adding the `HomeCtrl` on the navbar will actually not work either, because then you'll just have 2 instances of the same controller on the page.

Comment: I tired to created a separate controller and bound it to the navbar, but it's giving me the error unknow provider. Please see the link I referred at bottom.

Comment: your link was describing specifically using ng-controller inside the partial.  You have the exact opposite problem.

Comment: Well, I also tried bound `NavCtrl` which does the something as my `HomeCtrl` to navbar, it's giving me same error: `Unknown provider: currentAuthProvider <- currentAuth <- NavCtrl` I'm pretty sure everything else in my code have correct syntax and works.

Comment: can you post the code for that? `Unknown provider` should be something easy to track down....

Comment: See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wD3sVuYA4FF7a6CJoWFG?p=preview) for the code, the page is loading with error because of `ng-controller=NavCtrl` on index.html

Comment: well that clearly will never work, since you are trying to inject a resolve from `HomeCtrl` into `NavCtrl`.  if using resolves is the only way that you can accomplish this, then you should consider putting the `NavCtrl` on a parent abstract state, so that it can have it's own resolve chain, then put the `ui-view` for your `HomeCtrl` in the template for the `NavCtrl`.