# How can load partial view via angularjs ng-view and ng-route directives

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am completely new in Angular.
I want to load two different partial views with singleton controller by using ng-Route and ng-view.But every time when I executed below SpecialFields.cshtml that I got this type of [error](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=SpecialFields&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Aunpr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.8%2F%24injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3D%2524routeProvider%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A32793%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A6%3A412%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A32793%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A43%3A174%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A32793%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A40%3A432)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20e%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A32793%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A41%3A158)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.invoke%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A32793%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A41%3A243)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A32793%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A39%3A418)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A32793%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A40%3A19%0A%20%20%20%20at%20q%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A32793%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A355)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A32793%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A39%3A319).

I have searched many times and test a lot of points in stack overflow like this:
[angular multiple routes sharing one controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27493495/angular-multiple-routes-sharing-one-controller).
But code didn't work properly.

How can i solve this problem and how can I render partial views by ng-view and ng-route?
Thanks in advance

SpecialField.cshtml  is:

```
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="~/App/Patients/SpecialFields/specialFieldController.js"></script>
    <script src="~/App/Common/Services/StorageService.js"></script>
    <div class="row" style="font-family:BYekan">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="portlet light portlet-fit bordered">
                <div class="portlet-title">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <i class=" fa fa-cog font-green"></i>
                        <span class="caption-subject font-green bold uppercase">SpecialFields config</span>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="portlet-body" ng-app="SpecialFields" ng-controller="SpecialFieldsController">
                    <div class="row" style="margin:0 1px;direction:rtl">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="row panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <form name="frm" class="form-inline" >
                                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                            <label for="fieldname" class="bold control-label">Field Name</label>
                                            <span class="required">*</span>
                                            <input type="text" name="fieldname" id="fieldname" class="form-control" required ng-model="specialfieldname" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group  col-md-5 col-md-pull-1" >
                          <label for="fieldtype" class="bold control-label">Field Type:</label>
                                            <span class="required"> * </span>
                                            <select id="fieldtype" class="form-control" ng-model="specialfieldtype" ng-options="option for option in [Item1,Item2]">
                                                <option value="" class="placeholder" selected disabled>Item1</option>
                                            </select>
                                            <button class="btn btn-primary " type="submit" ng-click="addSpecialfield()">
                                                Add
                                                <span class="fa fa-plus-square-o" style="padding-right:5px;"></span>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class=" col-md-12">
                            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="sfields">
                                <thead>

                                    <tr>
                                        <th> Index</th>
                                        <th>Field name</th>
                                        <th>Field Type</th>
                                        <th>Edit</th>
                                        <th>Delete</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr ng-repeat="specialfield in specialfields">

                                        <td class="col-sm-2">
                                            {{$index+1}}
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="col-sm-4">
                                            {{ specialfield.specialfieldname }}
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="col-sm-4">
                                            {{ specialfield.specialfieldtype }}
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="col-sm-1">
                                            <a href="#/update" class="btn btn-default">
                                                Edit
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span>
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="col-sm-1">
                                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deleteSpecialfield(specialfield)">
                                                Delete
                                                <span class="fa fa-remove"></span>
                                            </a>

                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

this is specialFieldController.js

```
var isHtml5Compatible = document.createElement('canvas').getContext != undefined;

if (isHtml5Compatible) {
    initiateLocalStorage();

}

function initiateLocalStorage() {
    // Create the AngularJS app
    var app = angular.module('SpecialFields', ['common']);
    app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            controller: 'SpecialFieldsController',
            templateUrl: '/List.html'
        })
        .when('/update', {
            controller: 'SpecialFieldsController',
            templateUrl: '/Update.html'
        })
    });


    // Create the Controller
    app.controller('SpecialFieldsController', ['$scope', 'getLocalStorage', function ($scope, getLocalStorage) {

        //Read the Sfield List from LocalStorage
        $scope.specialfields = getLocalStorage.getSpecialfields();


        //Count the SpecialFields List
        $scope.count = $scope.specialfields.length;


        //Add Sfield - using AngularJS push to add sfield in the sfield Object
        //Call BindTable_SpecialField to update the locally stored Sfield List
        //Reset the AngularJS SpecialField scope
        //Update the Count
        $scope.addSpecialfield = function () {
            $scope.specialfields.push({'specialfieldname': $scope.specialfieldname, 'specialfieldtype': $scope.specialfieldtype });
            getLocalStorage.BindTable_SpecialField($scope.specialfields);
            //$scope.sfno = '';
            $scope.specialfieldname = '';
            $scope.specialfieldtype = '';
            $scope.count = $scope.specialfields.length;
        };

        //Delete Sfield - Using AngularJS splice to remove the sfield row from the sfield list
        //All the Update sfield to update the locally stored sfield List
        //Update the Count
        $scope.deleteSpecialfield = function (specialfield) {
            $scope.specialfields.splice($scope.specialfields.indexOf(specialfield), 1);
            getLocalStorage.BindTable_SpecialField($scope.specialfields);
            $scope.count = $scope.specialfields.length;
        };
    }]);
}
```

and this is StorageService.js

```
var storageService = angular.module('common', []);
storageService.factory('getLocalStorage', function () {
    var specialfieldList = {};
    return {
        list: specialfieldList,
        BindTable_SpecialField: function (SpecialfieldsArr) {
            if (window.localStorage && SpecialfieldsArr) {
                //Local Storage to add Data
                localStorage.setItem("specialfields", angular.toJson(SpecialfieldsArr));
            }
            specialfieldList = SpecialfieldsArr;

        },
        getSpecialfields: function () {
            //Get data from Local Storage
            specialfieldList = angular.fromJson(localStorage.getItem("specialfields"));
            return specialfieldList ? specialfieldList : [];
        }
    };

});
```

> ** Edit 2: Div with class portlet-body will have ng-view directive and will be my placeholder of my views.all of codes in this div will move
>   to List.html.another html file that will be rendered is  Update.html
>   which it renders when Edit button will be clicked.

Comment: Have you checked all scripts are loading? That error can also be displayed if there are syntax errors in your code also. Using same controller for multiple routes isn't common but shouldn't cause a problem either

Comment: note...you never injected `'ngRoute'` as module dependency

Comment: Yes I checked it thousand times.I have just one controller and I mainly I want to load update.html.The default partial view is list.html

Comment: there are two different modules.one of them is about local storage and I called it common module .specialField is module that has specialFieldController

Comment: right but to use ngRoute ...it is also a module and needs to be injected

Comment: Yes you're right .I injected it but it had this error again

Comment: will also confuse you if you think that the outer `ng-controller="SpecialFieldsController"` will be same controller instance as what you declare in the routing...will be multiple instances

Comment: So what do I do exactly?

Comment: need to solve module error first. Suggest commenting out the inner code of controller and service so just the component declarations exist and see what happens

Comment: I inject the 'ngRoute' to module and fix the error.but there is no redirecting to update.html when I click Edit Button

Comment: are those templates in root of your site? Can inspect the request for them in browser dev tool network also. And you can add a `$routeChangeError` handler as well

Comment: no there are in app/patients/specialField folders

Comment: well paths shown are for site root ...look at network requests. Also don't see any ng-view

Comment: So how do I give this path?I have to give a relative path?

Comment: relative or absolute doesn't matter but it needs to be correct. Using a leading `/` makes it absolute starting at site root