# Invoke service/factory outside of controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, angular-services

I have a `userService` that deals with all user functionality.  In order to populate it with data my `_Layout.cshtml` creates a global `currentUser` variable which I then want to put into my `userService`.  How can I do this during bootstrap?

It feels like I should be able to do something like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [...]);
var userService = myApp.create("userService");
userService.setUser(currentUser);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `run` to perform this before the controllers are used. Something along the lines of:

```
myApp.run(['userService', function(userService){
  userService.setUser(currentUser); // Consider injecting currentUser, too...
}]);
```

If it needs to be done earlier than the `run` events are triggered (though, generally, for this sort of stuff `run` should suffice), you'll probably want to put it in a `config` function (`myApp.config(/*etc.*/);`).

However, those cannot access typical `Service` providers, so you'll have to do it a bit more custom: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21650337/624590