# inject service[declared in separate file] in app.config or use it in a controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I am trying to use the code from [here to show routes only when a promise is TRUE](http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/show-route-only-after-all-promises-are-resolved/)

I am following this for my directory structure

```
app
 - Orders
   -orders.html
   -OrderController.js
   -OrderService.js
```

**Main-Config** [`app.js`]

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','ngAnimate','ui.bootstrap','myApp.OrderController']);
myApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
 $locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: true,
  requireBase: false
});
  $routeProvider
  .when('/orders', {
    templateUrl: 'orders/orders.html',
    controller: 'OrderController',
    resolve:{
        customerExpenses: function(OrderService){
            return OrderService.getOrders($route.current.params.customerName);
        }
    }
  })
})
```

**OrderService.js**

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('OrderService', ['$http', function($http) {
  var sdo = {
    getNames: function() {
      var promise = $http({ 
        method: 'GET', 
        url: ''
      });
      promise.success(function(data, status, headers, conf) {
        return data;
      });
      return promise;
    }
  }
  return sdo;
}]);
```

I have tried the `Accepted` answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937267/inject-service-in-app-config), and one of the suggestion from another SO article

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .service('FooService', function(){
    //...etc
  })
  .config(function(FooServiceProvider){
    //...etc
  });
```

As I have my service in a different file, I am trying to determine if I can use it in app.js file without using `provider` or is that the only way to use service in `app.config`?

UPDATE 1:
If i want to use the service in a controller

```
angular.module('myApp.OrderController',[]).controller('OrderController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.displayed=[];
    $scope.displayed.push(OrderService.getNames());
});
```

I get `OrderService`  not available

Have tried this:

```
angular.module('myApp.OrderController',[]).controller('OrderController', ['$scope','OrderService',function ($scope) {
    $scope.displayed=[];
    $scope.displayed.push(OrderService.getNames());
}]);
```

followed example :

```
angular.
module('myServiceModule', []).
 controller('MyController', ['$scope','notify', function ($scope, notify) {
   $scope.callNotify = function(msg) {
     notify(msg);
   };
 }]).
factory('notify', ['$window', function(win) {
   var msgs = [];
   return function(msg) {
     msgs.push(msg);
     if (msgs.length == 3) {
       win.alert(msgs.join("\n"));
       msgs = [];
     }
   };
 }]);
```

but can not use my service. my controller and service are in different files

I added this question here as I feel they are somewaht related.

Comment: you need to create provider if you wanted to access that service in `config` block http://stackoverflow.com/a/28262966/2435473

Comment: OrderService is not injected, change your code in very first line

Comment: @AliAdravi `OrderService` is injected in resolve function..

Comment: What's the exact reason for having it in config? Service provider helps to configure the service before it was instantiated. It doesn't matter in which file it was defined.

Comment: @estus: As part of my learning, I came across article i mentioned and wanted to try the code with my sample project.

Answer (score 0):

You have not injected your service OrderService, change your code in very first line

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','ngAnimate', ....'OrderService'])
myApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, OrderService){
....
})
```

Rest of the code looks good