# Angularjs: Inject Service in app.config such that to safeguard against minification

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to inject a service in app.config as illustrated in Inject service in app.config. However, minification breaks the app. How to overcome this?

This doesn't work with minification:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/',
        {
            templateUrl: "partials/editor.html",
            controller: "AppCtrl",
            resolve: {
                       //Following method doesn't work with minification
                        data: getData
                     }
        })
     function getData (dbService) {
         return dbService.getData();
     }
}]);
```

Please note the following code doesn't work: (Typescript does not allow compilation)

```
['dbService',function getData(dbService){
               return dbService.getData();
}]
```

Comment: Ok.  You should try the $inject method of annotating.  See my updated answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to safeguard against minification, you need to annotate (see Dependency Annotation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)) the data function like you did with the config function.

There are two ways to do this.

### 1.

Instead of passing a function, pass an array with the names of the dependencies and the function

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/',
    {
        templateUrl: "partials/editor.html",
        controller: "AppCtrl",
        resolve: {
            //annotate this to prevent against minification
            data: ['dbService', getData]
        }
    })

    function getData (dbService) {
        return dbService.getData();
    }
}]);
```

### 2.

Add your dependencies to a $inject property on your function

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/',
        {
            templateUrl: "partials/editor.html",
            controller: "AppCtrl",
            resolve: {
                //function annotated below
                data: getData
            }
        })

    //annotate this function with $inject so proper dependencies injected after minification
    getData.$inject = ['dbService'];
    function getData (dbService) {
        return dbService.getData();
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Tried it gives Error: [ng:areq] https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/areq?p0=fn&p1=not%20a%20function,%20got%20undefined

Comment: Please post what you have now.  That's an internal angular error which I wouldn't expect with this code.  Perhaps you didn't wrap the function in the array correctly?

Comment: Looked at your update.  You still aren't annotating the function in resolve.  Check out my edit and see if that works for you

Comment: Thanks a lot, the first array method is also working. I was trying to directly array annotate as shown in the question which was giving a typescript error.

Comment: You're welcome.  Angular is a bit tricky at first with some new patterns you have to learn.  FWIW, I generally prefer the $inject method of annotating as I find it more readable

Comment: I just tried the $inject method it gave me the following error. 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'dbService' of undefined'

Comment: Interesting.  I would expect to see that if you were trying to read a dbService of some null object.  e.g.  var x = null;  x.dbService();  Where is that error happening in your code?

Comment: Happens exactly where I try to invoke the service through $inject. However, at the same time ['service',functionCall] works.