# Inject service in app.config?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angularjs-injector, angularjs-config

I want to inject a service into app.config any idea please ?I want to inject a service into app.config any idea please ?I want to inject a service into app.config any idea please ?

**app.js**

```
  'use strict';

angular.module('crud', [
  'ngRoute',
  'angular-jwt',
  'ngSails',
  'ngMessages',
  'ngResource'


])
  .config(function ($httpProvider,$routeProvider, $locationProvider,$sailsProvider,jwtInterceptorProvider,User) {


  //$httpProvider.interceptors.push('jwtInterceptor');


     //console.log($sailsProvider);
    $routeProvider
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

  });
```

**Serviceuser.js**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('crud').service('User', function ($sails) {

    //console.log($sails);
    return {

        signup:  function (data) {
            return $sails.post('/api/user',data);       
        }
    } 

});
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937267/inject-service-in-app-config

Answer (score 0):

Here you go straight from the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services):

```
Registering a Service with $provide
You can also register services via the $provide service inside of a module 's config function:


angular
  .module('myModule', [])
  .config(['$provide ',
    function($provide) {
      $provide.factory('serviceId ', function() {
        var shinyNewServiceInstance;
        // factory function body that constructs shinyNewServiceInstance
        return shinyNewServiceInstance;
      });
    }
  ]);


This technique is often used in unit tests to mock out a service'
s dependencies.
```

Hope this helps.

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('example.app', [])
    .config(['$provide',
      function($provide) {
        $provide.factory('serviceId', function() {
          var shinyNewServiceInstance;
          // factory function body that constructs shinyNewServiceInstance
          return shinyNewServiceInstance;
        });
      }
    ])
    .controller('ExampleController', ExampleController)
    .service('exampleService', exampleService);

  exampleService.$inject = ['$http'];

  function ExampleController(exampleService) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.update = function(person, index) {
      exampleService.updatePeople(person).then(function(response) {
        vm.persons = response;
      }, function(reason) {
        console.log(reason);
      });
    };
  }


  // good practice to use uppercase variable for URL, to denote constant.    
  //this part should be done in a service

  function exampleService($http) {
    var URL = 'https://beta.test.com/auth/authenticate/',
      data = {},
      service = {
        updatePeople: updatePeople
      };

    return service;

    function updatePeople(person) {
      //person would be update of person.
      return $http
        .post(URL, person)
        .then(function(response) {
          return response.data;
        }, function(response) {
          return response;
        });
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: can u put an example ?

Answer (score -1):

you can use like:

```
angular.module('app', ["ui.router"])
.config(function config ($stateProvider){
    $stateProvider.state("index", {
      url:"",
      controller: "FirstCtrl as first",
      templateUrl: "first.html"
    })
    .state("second", {
      url:"/second",
      controller:"SecondCtrl as second",
      templateuRL:"second.html"
    })
})
```

here is the full working example with [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ren3t89gT71lOfOVMnVu?p=info)