# How to pass parameter from .run to .config?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I work on my angularjs ui-route project.
in `.run()` core I put some variable in named `clientid` to `$rootScope`.

At some point I need to use stored variable in `.config()` core.

I know that I can't use `$rootScope` service in `.config()` core.

So my question is how to pass `clientid` variable from `$rootScope` to `.config()`.Maybe I can use any another service?

Comment: that depends on how you are writing a service , you can check this answer for more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937267/inject-service-in-app-config

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ofcourse, using $rootScope would be wrong decision. Because no one prefers to pollute global scope and there are other reasons as well. You could consider creating an constant called as `settings` and utilize that in wherever you needed in any angular components like `.run` block, `config` phase, `service`, `provider`, etc.

```
angular.module('mainModule').constant('settings', {
   clientId: 1123 //some inital value
})
```

Though you could override this value from your config phase.

```
angular.module('mainModule').config(['settings', configFn])

function configFn(settings){
    //routes registers here

    //other awesome stuf

    //set clientId here
    //Assuming your clientId will be available, no async operation.
    if(someValue === 1)
      settings.clientId = 'asd12';  
    else
      settings.clientId = 'asd34';  
}
```

Thereafter you can use that constant inside your `run` block

```
angular.module('mainModule').run(['settings', runBlock])

function runBlock(settings){
   console.log(settings);
}
```

> **Note**: The reason behind selecting `constant` is, this flavor can be available as injectable in any angular components.

Comment: Pankaj thanks for post.Is app module should be main module?

Comment: @Michael yupe.. `config` & `run` blog should applied on main module to configure & initialize something before app gets bootstrapped.

Comment: Pankaj , can I use constant in run core?