# Service injection in config. AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, parameters, angular-ui-router, config, inject

I have this service:

```
app.service("UserService", function(){

    var userService = {};
    userService.userInfo = [
        {firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe"},
        {firstName: "Carl", lastName: "Smith"}
        ];
    return userService;
});
```

And I want to inject it into a .config to define routes (for which I'm using ui-router)

```
app.config(["userService", function($stateProvider, userService){
     $stateProvider
    .state("#",{
        templateUrl: "index.html",
        controller: "UserListController"
    })
    .state('users', {
        url: '/user/:username',
         templateUrl: "view/userProfile.html",
        controller: "UserListController",
         params: { username: userService.userInfo[0].firstName}
           })
...
```

This isn't working properly. Any ideas on can I inject the data in that service to be accessed by the .config?

Thank you :)

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937267/inject-service-in-app-config

Comment: Maybe it's just a typo in your quetion, but your service name start with an uppercase but when you include it you forgot this uppercase

Comment: No it's not about that I think. The problem is it seems it cannot access the userService.userInfo[0].firstName in params. If i just change that for a string it works perfectly fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the configuration you can only access to providers, in your case you can access to `UserServiceProvider` by injecting it in your `app.config` like this :

```
app.config(function(UserServiceProvider){
    // Config stuffs...
})
```

With this provider you can access your service property with `$get()` like this by example :

```
UserServiceProvider.$get().userInfo[0]
```

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/kmJmzShvhpe4PN6GOFs2) is a working plunker

Comment: But how can I can access the data inside the .config for the routes? The main goal is that the url will be according to the username

Comment: @N.Car You need to replace `params: { username: userService.userInfo[0].firstName}` by `params:{username: UserServiceProvider.$get().userInfo[0].firstName}` and to include `UserServiceProvider` in the config declaration

Comment: Works!!! Thank you very much! 
So basically when you want something to be injected in a .config you need to make it a provider and then user the $get() in order to obtain what's inside of it?

Comment: Not really to make it a provider, but to use its provider and then yes use $get(). But I don't think t's a proper way to use providers and $get().

Answer (score 0):

For injections in AngularJS, if you are going to give the names you are going to inject, you need to give all the names and the same way you declared it.

In this case:

```
app.config(["$stateProvider", "UserService", function($stateProvider, userService){
```

Comment: I just added it but it's still not working. I think he's not recognising this userService.userInfo[0].firstName as a string. If I change it for {username: "click me"} it works just fine

Comment: No, actually it doesn't work when I inhect the userService as you said.

{
app.config(["$stateProvider", "userService", function($stateProvider, userService){
     $stateProvider
    .state("#",{
        templateUrl: "index.html",
        controller: "UserListController"
    })
    .state('users', {
        url: '/user/:username',
         templateUrl: "view/userProfile.html",
        controller: "UserListController",
         params: { username: "click me"}
}

Answer (score 0):

Constants are injectable in both the config phase and the run phase:

```
app.constant("UserConstant", {
    userInfo:[
        {firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe"},
        {firstName: "Carl", lastName: "Smith"}
    ]
});
```

From the Docs:

> ## constant(name, value);
>
> Register a constant service with the `$injector`, such as a string, a number, an array, an object or a function. Like the [value](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#value), it is not possible to inject other services into a constant.
>
> But unlike [value](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#value), a constant **can be injected into a module configuration function** (see [angular.Module](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#config)) and it cannot be overridden by an AngularJS [decorator](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#decorator).
>
> [Angular $provider API Reference - constant](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#constant)

Comment: Thanks!! It also works! I'm still learning AngularJS and didn't know about constant. Will definitely look into it :)