# How to get the http get response data value to outer scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
.config([
    '$provide',
    function ($provide) {
        'use strict';



        var initInjector = angular.injector(['ng']);

        var apiUrl;

        initInjector.get('$http').get('customer/api/')

       .then(function (response) {
            console.log("dddd" + response.data.url);

            apiUrl = response.data.url;

          });

       console.log(apiUrl);
```

//This print as Undefined

```
        $provide.constant('GLOBAL', global);
    }
]);
```

when i print the apiUrl value tetrived from http get service print as undefined.

can some one hep me to get the value of response.data.url to outer scope.

Edit:

```
    var apiUrl;

    var initInjector = angular.injector(['ng']);

    var self = this;

    initInjector.get('$http').get('customer/api/')

    .then(function(response) {

        console.log("ddddd" + response.data.url); //print value
        self.apiUrl = response.data.url;

        console.log("selff" +self.apiUrl); //print value
    });

    console.log("outerr" +self.apiUrl); // print undefined
```

Comment: Then don't do your `console.log` call until you know you have the response.  You have the response when the REST call finishes, so do your printing/updating of the UI there.  You can also add error handling and respond appropriately as well.

Comment: i want to get apiUrl value for passing to service in angularjs

Comment: `$http.get` is an asynchronous call, use `console.log()` inside of `then()`. Work with promises and not variables (return `apiUrl`)

Comment: You can move your code into service, where you want to pass apiUrl.

Comment: It would help us to know where the data is needed. This pattern could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937267/inject-service-in-app-config

Answer (score 0):

Promises can't be used like synchronous code because they return a promise immediately. You should wait for the promise to complete before setting your global values.

Instead of doing

```
a = {}
a.key1 = Promise().then(()=>{
  return 1
})
a.key2 = Promise().then(()=>{
  return 2
})
```

Do something like this instead (with `bluebird`):

```
Promise.all([
    Promise().then(()=>{
      return 1
    }),
    Promise().then(()=>{
      return 2        
    }),
]).then(result => {
  a.key1 = result[0]
  a.key2 = result[1]
})
```

Alternatively you can look into the async/await syntax es7 provides

Comment: i dont use es7.this is legacy code base.can you modify my code accordingly.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#constant

I think you might want to look into using some other methods for angular specifically

Comment: var a = {};
        
        var initInjector = angular.injector(['ng']);
    
     initInjector.get('$http').get('api/customer')
     
     .then(function(response) {
            
      console.log("ddddd" + response.data.url);
      a.key1 = response.data.url;
        });
     
        
     
     console.log(a.key1);        still get undefined

Answer (score 0):

Declare a global variable and then assign value after http call.

```
var apiUrl ='';
.config([
    '$provide',
    function ($provide) {
        'use strict';
        var initInjector = angular.injector(['ng']);

        var apiUrl;

        initInjector.get('$http').get('customer/api/').then(function (response) {
            console.log("dddd" + response.data.url);

            this.apiUrl = response.data.url;

          });

       console.log(this.apiUrl);
```

Comment: empty value for apiUrl

Comment: first check you are getting apiUrl on your console.log statement or not

Comment: im gettting it check with log