# Angular can't find created provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

I have app that use webpack and babel, the code look like this:

**app.js**

```
import angular from 'angular';
import 'jquery';
import components from './components/index';
import services from './services/index';
import './app.css';

angular.module('app', [components.name, services.name])
    .config((rpc) => {
        rpc.setup('rpc.scm');
    });
```

**services/index.js**

```
import angular from 'angular';
import rpc from './rpc';

var module = angular.module('services', []);

module.provider('rpc', rpc);

export default module;
```

**services/rpc.js**

```
import $ from 'jquery';

export default function() {
   var service = {};
   this.setup = function(uri) {
       // create service based on system.describe
   };
   this.$get = function() {
       return service;
   }
};
```

and I got error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: rpc
```

I don't get any errors from webpack.

Comment: check this part: .config((rpc) => {rpc.setup('rpc.scm');}); where are you getting "rpc" from?
**Note**: you can only inject providers inside .config!

Comment: @PaoloMangia it's `module.provider('rpc', rpc);`

Comment: you can' t do it that way. it only accepts: nameofproviderProvider.

Comment: please take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966013/angularjs-inject-provider-to-module-config

Comment: @PaoloMangia Chaning rpc to rpcProvider in config solved the issue, you can add this as an answer.

Comment: glad it helped, added as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the provider should be injected as follows:

```
angular.module('app', [components.name, services.name])
 .config((rpcProvider) => {
});
```

since .config only accepts nameofprovider + Provider (camel case).

more info here: [AngularJS - Inject provider to module.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966013/angularjs-inject-provider-to-module-config)