# angularjs: could not inject a factory

Tags: angularjs

I have a factory,

```
var commonFactories = angular.module('commonFactories', []).
factory('acampaign', function () {
    // return {'a' : 1};
    return "hello";
});
```

and I am injecting it to a module,

```
angular.module("campaign", ["ngRoute", "ngResource", "commonServices", "commonFactories"]).
// configure campaign module
config(["acampaign", function(acampaign) {

...

}
```

Angular throws error saying it cannot instantiate `campaign` module,

```
Failed to instantiate module campaign due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.12/$injector/unpr?p0=acam...
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:8000/static/assets/angularjs/angular.min.js:6:417
    at http://localhost:8000/static/assets/angularjs/angular.min.js:38:7
    at d (http://localhost:8000/static/assets/angularjs/angular.min.js:36:13)
    at Object.e [as invoke] (http://localhost:8000/static/assets/angularjs/angular.min.js:36:283)
    at d (http://localhost:8000/static/assets/angularjs/angular.min.js:34:498)
    at http://localhost:8000/static/assets/angularjs/angular.min.js:35:99
    at s (http://localhost:8000/static/assets/angularjs/angular.min.js:7:302)
    at g (http://localhost:8000/static/assets/angularjs/angular.min.js:34:399)
    at ab (http://localhost:8000/static/assets/angularjs/angular.min.js:38:135
```

Comment: please see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903338/angularjs-dependency-injection-of-value-inside-of-module-config

Comment: @sylwester bt factories are providers right? If so above code completely valid.

Comment: @larner010 please read here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#conclusion

Comment: Thanx I am reading it right now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your acampaign factory is acampaignProvider in the config function. factories and services are essentially sugar syntax for providers. Look at provider in the [guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) the provider recipe section

Comment: I am aware of it. I dont understand why my above code wont work. I would appreciate little explanation on it. :)

Comment: Basically i think is because a factory register a provider and at the time the  config function runs the factory is still a provider and inside angular they append "Provider" to the name. I think is just some internal convention.

Comment: Thanx for the help, I am reading the doc you pointed earlier.